# Cannot stop nodejs function

Tags: node.js, webtask

I have a nodejs serverless backend which takes an interger and then execute some code. My problem is that if I send a string, I still get a 200 code response with null data.

To stop the function and send an error message I'm trying to check if the request is an interger with `if` and `else` statements but its not working. So, is it possible to do it like this, or is there a better way to stop the execution and send an error?

```
app.post('/xrp', (req, res) => {
  axios.get('https://www.surbtc.com/api/v2/markets/btc-clp/ticker')
    .then(response => {
      var clpbtc = parseFloat(response.data.ticker.min_ask[0]);
      if (typeof clpbtc === 'number') {
        coinTicker('bittrex', 'XRP_BTC')
        .then(response => {
          var xrpbtc = response.rawData.Bid;
          var exchangeRate = clpbtc * xrpbtc;
          if (xrpbtc) {
            var cantidadCLP = req.body.numero;
            var cantidadXRP = parseFloat(req.body.numero) / exchangeRate;
            var fee = 0.025;
            var oppositeFee = 0.975
            var totalCompraXRP = cantidadXRP * oppositeFee;
            res.status(200).json({ "cantidadCLP" : cantidadCLP, "cantidadXRP" : cantidadXRP, "fee": fee, "oppositeFee": oppositeFee, "totalCompraXRP": totalCompraXRP})
          } else {
            res.sendStatus(500).send("No válido2")
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            res.sendStatus(500).json(error);
        })
      } else {
        res.sendStatus(500).send("No válido")
      }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        res.sendStatus(500).json(error);
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're parsing the parameter as a float anyway so even if you send a `string`, it will convert to a `number` and your query will simply return no data, hence the null response.

```
parseFloat('This is a string')
// => NaN

typeof parseFloat('This is a string')
// => 'number'
```

This is a weird property of javascript, where `typeof NaN == 'number'`

To accommodate for this, change your code to the following:

```
.then(response => {
      var clpbtc = parseFloat(response.data.ticker.min_ask[0]);
      if (!isNaN(clpbtc)) {
        coinTicker('bittrex', 'XRP_BTC')
```

Now, if you pass in a string, you should get a `500` response.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it's not working. I still get a 200 response

Comment: I recommend you add console.log()s to find which path the interpreter takes.